# Catalog Search Indexer runs indefinitely with alot of backlog

Tags: magento2.3, cron, indexing

I've run into this issue with my indexers lately where my Catalog Search Indexer will run indefinitely with a lot of backlogged tasks.[image: indexer:status]
And if, and when, I edit any product or even add any new attribute without even assigning it to an attribute set this backlog will increase exponentially and will cause certain, if not most, products to disappear **COMPLETELY** from the frontend, but **NOT** from the backend. I had this issue the day before where I found my Catalog Search indexer giving this when I run the `indexer:status` command

```
Catalog Search | Reindex required | Schedule | working (952 in backlog) | 2022-03-08 15:33:26|
```

My indexers will be delayed for hours before being completed, which is probably why the products disappear.

These are my current cron jobs I thought they might be relevant information to the issue I posed.
[image]

Can someone provide some insight as to why that may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen due to poor indexer optimization. If you have set it up in the schedule mode, it may be that the new process is "adding" itself to the waiting queue because the previous ones are still running - if your Catalog Search indexer has status "working" in the `indexer_state` table, it means that you can't run a new indexer job.

If you have made any changes to the native Magento indexer, try to optimize them.